# Find $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^n(x)}{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)} dx$.

Tags: calculus

> Find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\sin^n(x)}{\sin^n(x)+\cos^n(x)} dx$.

I was told to switch the limits of integration then add them. How can I do that here?

Comment: If you make the substitution $u = \frac{\pi}{2} - x$, what do you get?

Comment: Thanks for ruining the secret Daniel!

Comment: We get $\displaystyle \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{0} \dfrac{\sin^n(\frac{\pi}{2}-u)}{\sin^n((\frac{\pi}{2}-u))+\cos^n((\frac{\pi}{2}-u))}$.

Comment: @JohnRyan: You are missing a negative sign since $du = -dx$. After you fix that, use the identities $\sin(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-u) = \cos(u)$ and $\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-u) = \sin(u)$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 How does that help solve the question?

Comment: Next, use the "then add them" hint.

Comment: We get $\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^n x}{\sin^n x+\cos^n x}dx+ \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^n u}{\cos^n u+\sin^n u}du.$ Then what?

Comment: Change the dummy variable of integration in the second integral to $x$.

Comment: Ok, I still don't see how that helps.

Comment: We then have $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^n x}{\sin^n x+\cos^n x}dx+ \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos^n x}{\cos^n x+\sin^n x}dx \,.$$

Comment: Now add the two integrals.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Yes, then what?

Comment: What doe adding do?

Comment: @JohnRyan $I+I=\frac{\pi}{2}$.  What is $I$?

Comment: Why do they add to $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: What is the sum of the integrands?

Comment: It is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\pi/2} 1$